# Change CSS background from HTML select to pure white - Angular Project

Tags: html, css, select, safari, background

I have a **select** tag in my Angular project that I want it to look like others tags as you see in the image. What should I do to change CSS background from the **select** to be pure white as the others tags.

I've tried using `background: white; background-color: white;` in style but it still a shadow grey on it.

The final code is like this image: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weIJc.png)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ev6e4w?file=src%2Fassets%2Fbootstrap.min.css

Comment: can u create a stack blitz with a sample code ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @IlCorsaroNero https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ev6e4w?file=src%2Fassets%2Fbootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Bootstrap installed in you're project, Just add `form-control` class

Comment: Thank you Arta. I've done it already. The problem is that the select don't look like the other tags. It has a shadow gray on it.

Comment: for me it's okay and beautiful in chrome and firefox

Comment: Remember the ```css``` that you write for an element is always okay in Chrome & etc. but in Safari sometimes it's diffrent, try this
: ```-webkit-appearance: none;```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was using only in Safari, that's why the problem was happening.